# Setting width of an inner div to the width of the container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to modify the bootstrap css, I want the `.dropdown-menu` to expand to the full width of the container, but setting `width:100%` sets the width to parent width. I tried using jquery and this works but as the menus increase they don't fit into the container. how do I fix this such that each dropdown menu has the same width and fits the whole container from left to right? **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vhn0cgd4/)**

`jquery`

```
$(window).bind("load resize", function(){
$('.extend').width($('.container').width());
});
```

`html`

```
<div class="container">

  <!-- Static navbar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu extend">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu extend">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
  </nav>

</div> <!-- /container -->
```

Comment: Do you mean that the menu's should take the complete width of the container even on desktop?

Comment: yes.+768px the dropdown menus should all have the same width and extend to the entire width of container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(window).bind("load resize", function(){
    adjust();
 $('.extend').width($('.container').width());
});

function adjust(){
$('.dropdown-toggle').each(function(){
var left = ($('body').width()-$('.container').width())/2;
  $(this).parent().find('.dropdown-menu').css('margin-left','-'+($(this).offset().left-left)+'px');
 });
}
adjust();
```

Please try this out. Here is the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vhn0cgd4/2/).

Comment: But in your fiddle, if I remove `padding:0px` from my css, the menu shifts to the side of the body. I want it to stay within the limits of the container

Comment: Check the updated code and fiddle now. Now it doesn't depend on padding.